# python - beautifulsoup - TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Tag found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to extract images and links from a html string. It all works perfectly fine, however with some links that have a tag in the link contents it is throwing an error.

Example Link:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><strong>Link Text</strong></a>
```

Python Code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
links = soup.findAll('a')
for link in links:
    print link.contents # generates error
    print str(link.contents) # outputs [Link Text]
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Tag found
```

I don't really want to have to loop through any child tags in the link text, I simply want to return the raw contents, is this possible with BS?

Comment: raw contents == just the visible text? or do you want it to return `<strong>Link Text</strong>`?

Comment: sorry, I mean the text plus whatever the tags are, so in this case I'd like it to output <strong>Link Text</strong>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To grab just the text content of a tag, the [`element.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) lets you grab (stripped) text from the current element including tags:

```
print link.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

The first argument is used to join all text elements, and sitting `strip` to `True` means all text elements are first stripped of leading and trailing whitespace. This gives you neat processed text in most cases.

You can also use the [`.stripped_strings` iterable](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
print u' '.join(link.stripped_strings)
```

which is essentially the same effect, but you could choose to process or filter the stripped strings first.

To get the contents, use `str()` or `unicode()` on each child item:

```
print u''.join(unicode(item) for item in link)
```

which will work for both `Element` and `NavigableString` items contained.

Comment: yup - bs4 is a massive improvement in this regard

Comment: @JonClements: Now, if only they'd add that to the `NavigableText` type to (just return the text content as one item) and we'd be able to loop over a result set in one go without having to test for the attribute..

Comment: For me it says `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, although there **is** a content, i.e. I can `print` it just before an error.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: without context, I cannot help you. Perhaps ask a new question?

Comment: Aha, I found the problem! I was not the fist one it is that there is no method `get_text()`, [it is rather called `getText()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21939333/2388257) ☺

Comment: @Hi-Angel: you are using BeautifulSoup 3 then; my answer is for BeautifulSoup *4*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: know that BeautifulSoup 3 was discontinued in 2012; you really want to upgrade to the `beautifulsoup4` project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay, thank you. Here's actually a weird thing that I have installed package `python-bs4` from my repository, accordingly to info it said to be the fourth version. And `import` didn't worked for me :/  Then I installed some `python-beautifulsoup`, and it works, but since now I see it is a third version. So bizarre.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: version 4 uses the package name `bs4`; `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you can use str.

ex:

```py
print ''.join(str(item) for item in link)
```

Comment: This has already been explained in the accepted answer. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. You can show your support for an original answer by upvoting.