# 'NoneType' object is not callable beautifulsoup error while using get_text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I wrote  this code for extracting all text from a web page:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.pythonforbeginners.com').read())
print(soup.get_text())
```

The problem is I get this error:

```
print(soup.get_text())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: Take it one step at a time ... first look at the result of `urllib2.urlopen('http://www.pythonforbeginners.com')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is called `soup.getText()`, i.e. camelCased.

Why you get `TypeError` instead of `AttributeError` here is a mystery to me!

Comment: `getText()` is aliased to `get_text()` so this isn't it.

Comment: That could be version specific - I get the same error as the OP with v3.2.1, and it's fixed by changing to `getText()`.

Comment: Hmm good to know. I have 4x, but since he's importing using `from BeautifulSoup` we can be sure he doesn't! You may be right!

Answer (score 0):

As Markku suggests in the comments, I would recommend breaking your code up.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

URL = "http://www.pythonforbeginners.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.pythonforbeginners.com')
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.get_text())
```

If it's still not working, throw in some print statements to see what's going on.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

URL = "http://www.pythonforbeginners.com"
print("URL is {} and its type is {}".format(URL,type(URL)))
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.pythonforbeginners.com')
print("Page is {} and its type is {}".format(page,type(page))
html = page.read()
print("html is {} and its type is {}".format(html,type(html))
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print("soup is {} and its type is {}".format(soup,type(soup))
print(soup.get_text())
```