# Parsing application ld+Json with Beautifulsoup (findAll)

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

My current problem is that I want to parse the application JSON data of a website. But the website has multiple script tags with application data, and I'm trying to get them all and not only one.
I'm currently struggling to get this to work. I have the following code:

`return json.loads("".join(soup.findAll("script", {"type":"application/ld+json"})[1]))`

Does someone have an idea how to get rid of the list indices ([1]) and just print out every JSON data in a dict with findAll? When I remove the [1] I get the following error:

`sequence item 0: expected str instance, Tag found`

Full code:

```
def get_ld_json(url: str) -> dict: 
  parser = "html.parser"
  req = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, parser)
  return json.loads("".join(soup.findAll("script", {"type":"application/ld+json"})[1]))
```

Comment: `script` tags contain javascript, not JSON. I've yet to see (useful) `script` tags with just JSON data but I'd like to see some.

Comment: You might take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14264141/4476484. You can try `join([str(x) for x in your_list])`

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1346961239454700/Geschnetzeltes-Schweinefilet-in-Senfsahne.html , I'm trying to parse the recipe data and as you can see in the quellcode there are two application ld+json scripts. I wanna get both of these in one dict because other website (which i also want to parse with the script) only have one application ld+json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert multiple JSON objects to one, that would render the JSON invalid.

What you *can* do is create a `list` containing all the JSON objects, and loop over the list to get the correct data.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1346961239454700/Geschnetzeltes-Schweinefilet-in-Senfsahne.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = [
    json.loads(x.string) for x in soup.find_all("script", type="application/ld+json")
]
```

For example, to get the *names*, loop over the list (`data`) and access the "name" key:

```
for d in data:
    print(d["name"])
```

Which outputs:

```
Chefkoch
Geschnetzeltes Schweinefilet in Senfsahne
```

Comment: First, thanks for your help :). For the key "name" it works great, but when I search for example for the key "recipeIngredient" it gives an KeyError :/. Do you know why?

Comment: @Broump That's because the _first_ dictionary doesn't have that key. You can use `.get()` instead of `["key"]`. For example: `for d in data
    print(d.get("recipeIngredient", ""))`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now it works :D , Have a nice day ;)